# Generalisation of Fibonacci

Tags: fibonacci-numbers

Somehow a generalisation of the fibonacci numbers, do numbers created by the formula $ F(n) = F(n-1) + [F(n-1)-F(n-2)+F(n-3)-F(n-4)+F(n-5)-F(n-6).....]$ with $F(1) = 1$  have a specific name?

Comment: Your equation has two $F(n-1)$'s on the right.  Did you mean that?  For analogy with the Fibonacci sequences there should only be one.

Comment: Did you mean to write $F(n-1)$ twice? If you leave it out, the order 3 are usually called tribonacci, after that we just called them $n$-acci but I do not believe there is a standard accepted name    http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalizations_of_Fibonacci_numbers#Fibonacci_numbers_of_higher_order

Comment: Tribonacci, Tetrabonacci, Pentabonacci (ugh!), Fibonacci numbers of order $k$.

Comment: yes I do mean it, but if only the factors between the [] are a known sequence , then it would be F(n-1) + that sequence

Answer (score 0):

You need more starting terms than just one unless you define $F(0)$ and negative indices zero.  If you did not intend $F(n-1)$ to be on the right twice, there are some values [in Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalizations_of_Fibonacci_numbers#Higher_orders), which has links into [OEIS, this one for six on the right](http://oeis.org/A001592)